# Using if else statement inside functools.reduce

Tags: python, pyspark

i have created a function which is working fine , however, i would like to add if else statement inside function.reduce and im not sure if this is achievable. tried researching on func.reduce but there wasnt any information / use-case available on how i want to function to work. would need some advice if this is possible in python or should i go on another approach .

I have created this function which is working as expected, '

```
def tempJoin(df,targetField,targetTitle,condition,targetResult,otherwise,show=False,lowercase=False):
    case_conditions = list(zip(condition, targetResult))
    product_col = functools.reduce(
        lambda acc, x: acc.when(col(targetField).like(x[0]), F.lit(x[1])),case_conditions,F,).otherwise(otherwise)
    df = df.withColumn(targetTitle, product_col)

    if show:
        df.show(10)
        
    return df;
```

i am fully aware that i could go with this approach, but i feel this can be further optimise

```
def tempJoin(df,targetField,targetTitle,condition,targetResult,otherwise,show=False,lowercase=False):
    case_conditions = list(zip(condition, targetResult))
    if lowercase :
        product_col = functools.reduce(
            lambda acc, x: acc.when(lower(col(targetField)).like(x[0]), F.lit(x[1])),case_conditions,F,).otherwise(otherwise)        
    else :
        product_col = functools.reduce(
            lambda acc, x: acc.when(col(targetField).like(x[0]), F.lit(x[1])),case_conditions,F,).otherwise(otherwise)
    
    df = df.withColumn(targetTitle, product_col)

    if show:
        df.show(10)
        
    return df;
```

what i am trying to achieve is to add if else  of 'lowercase=True' , it will triggers within functools itself. something as this shown below

```
 product_col = functools.reduce(
            if lowercase:
                lambda acc, x: acc.when(lower(col(targetField)).like(x[0]), F.lit(x[1])),case_conditions,F,).otherwise(otherwise)
            else:
                lambda acc, x: acc.when(col(targetField).like(x[0]), F.lit(x[1])),case_conditions,F,).otherwise(otherwise)
```

is this achievable ?

Comment: just write a full function definition, the code is unreadable as it is.

Answer (score 2):

So you're looking for an "inline" if statement?  Python calls those *conditional expressions*.

The general syntax is `some_value if condition else other_value`

So your code would be:

```
product_col = functools.reduce(lambda ... if lowercase else lambda ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the ternary expression inside the `when` clause:

```
product_col = functools.reduce(
    lambda acc, x:
        acc.when(
            (lower(col(targetField)) if lowercase else col(targetField)).like(x[0]), 
            F.lit(x[1])
        ), case_conditions, F
).otherwise(otherwise)
```